# help with onseek and selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-scrollable

I am using this:

```
 $(function() {

            // initialize scrollable
            window.api = $("div.scrollable").scrollable({
                clickable: true,
                activeClass: "active",
                onSeek: function() {
                    alert("current position is: " + this.getIndex());
                    //remove highlighting from all images
                    $(".items img").removeClass("selected");
                    var position = this.getIndex().toString();
                    var thisItem = $(".items:nth-child(" + position + ")");
                    //var thisItem = allItems(this.getIndex);
                    alert("item is: " + $(this).attr('alt'));
                    changeimage($(".items:nth-child(2)"));
                }
            }).circular().autoscroll({
                interval: 4000,
                api: true,
                autoplay: false,
                steps: 1

            });

        });
```

(just testing) so that I can parse the current item to my changeimage() function
But all I get in my alerts are undefined.
WHat do I need to do here to get the current item

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current item using the api by calling the following:

```
var currentItem = window.api.getItems().eq(window.api.getIndex());
```

The getIndex() function gets a numerical position of the element and getItems gets a jquery object with all the items within it.  Using the eq() function asks for the item at the given position.

I've sometimes had bad luck with it, but within the onSeek callback, you should be able to use 'this' variable in place of the windows.api which would look like:

```
var currentItem = this.getItems().eq(this.getIndex());
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. As `this` points to the api inside the jquery TOOLS functions, you can write it even shorter: `var currentItem = this.getItems().eq(this.getIndex());`